# Ionic 2 and ng-model

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-ngmodel

I truly feel as an early adopter because Google couldn't find a way to fix my issue :)

I'm somehow getting this error:

> Can't bind to 'ng-model' since it isn't a known native property

I don't see @Component in Ionic, so the page is configured like this:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
  directives: [Select]
})
```

and my template is this:

```
<ion-input floating-label>
  <ion-label>Search text...</ion-label>
  <input type="text"  [(ng-model)]="searchInput" />
</ion-input>
```

I'm using Ionic 2.

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Angular 2, you should use [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html) in the template, and not `ng-model`.

Comment: @yarons pleasee, could you update the `ngModel` link, is broken